# WinError2 File Specified Not Found (Python 3.9)

Tags: python, file, sharing

I don't know a lot in python, and I need to make a UDP P2P file sharing app/code. Never used python before so excuse my lack of knowledge. I need help getting this Error:

```
    `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified`
```

and here is my code of server.py:

```
import os
import socket
import time

host = input("Host Name: ")
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)


try:
    sock.connect((host, 22222))
    print("Connected Successfully")
except:
    print("Unable to connect")
    exit(0)


file_name = sock.recv(100).decode()
file_size = sock.recv(100).decode()


with open("./rec/" + file_name, "wb") as file:
    c = 0
  
    start_time = time.time()

    
    while c <= int(file_size):
        data = sock.recv(1024)
        if not (data):
            break
        file.write(data)
        c += len(data)

   
    end_time = time.time()

print("File transfer Complete. Total time: ", end_time - start_time)


sock.close()
```

This code is comprised of multiple websites and githubs, so please excuse me if you see any copying.

client.py:

````
import os
import socket
import time


sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind((socket.gethostname(), 22222))
sock.listen(5)
print("Host Name: ", sock.getsockname())


client, addr = sock.accept()


file_name = input("File Name:")
file_size = os.path.getsize(file_name)


client.send(file_name.encode())
client.send(str(file_size).encode())


with open(file_name, "rb") as file:
    c = 0
   
    start_time = time.time()

   
    while c <= file_size:
        data = file.read(1024)
        if not (data):
            break
        client.sendall(data)
        c += len(data)

    
    end_time = time.time()

print("File Transfer Complete. Total time: ", end_time - start_time)

sock.close()


      ```
````

Comment: You have posted the same code for `server.py` and `client.py`

Comment: hahaha my bad. Thanks, fixed it.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full traceback of the exception.  That should tell you where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you encountered is due to the file not being found. Most likely it is the `client.py` file that reported the error. You should check the file exists before you try to open it.

```
file_name = input("File Name: ")
# Ensure the file exists
if not os.path.isfile(file_name):
    print(f"File not found: {file_name}")
    exit(0)
```

There are a number of errors in the code due to the fact that you have copy and pasted from different sources. The following code should work for you, I've added comments to explain how it works.

If there is something that needs further explanation let me know in the comments.

**server.py**:

```
import os
import socket
import time

SERVER_HOST = "0.0.0.0"
SERVER_PORT = 22222
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 # Receive 1024 bytes at a time (1kb)
SEPARATOR = ":::::"

SERVER_FOLDER = "./rec/" # Location to save file

# Create the server socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# Bind the socket to the host address and port
sock.bind((SERVER_HOST, SERVER_PORT))

# Enable server to accept connections
sock.listen()
print(f"Server listening {SERVER_HOST}:{SERVER_PORT}")

# Accept client connection
client_socket, address = sock.accept()
print(f"Client {address} connected.")

# Receive the file information
received = client_socket.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).decode()

# Split the string using the separator
file_name, file_size = received.split(SEPARATOR)

print(f"File name: '{file_name}'")
print(f"File size: '{file_size}'")

# Set the path where the file is to be saved
save_path = os.path.join(SERVER_FOLDER, file_name)

with open(save_path, "wb") as file:
    bytes_received = 0
    start_time = time.time()
    while True:
        data = client_socket.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
        if not (data):
            break
        file.write(data)
        bytes_received += len(data)
    end_time = time.time()

print(f"File transfer Complete. {bytes_received} of {file_size} received. Total time: {end_time - start_time}")

# Close the client socket
client_socket.close()

# Close the server socket
sock.close()
```

**client.py**:

```
import os
import socket
import time

SERVER_PORT = 22222
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 # Send 1024 bytes at a time (1kb)
SEPARATOR = ":::::"

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = socket.gethostname()

print(f"Connecting to {host}:{SERVER_PORT}")
sock.connect((host, SERVER_PORT))
print("Connected.")

file_name = input("File Name: ")

# Ensure the file exists
if not os.path.isfile(file_name):
    print(f"File not found: {file_name}")
    exit(0)

# Get the file size
file_size = os.path.getsize(file_name)

# Send file_name and file_size as a single string
sock.send(f"{file_name}{SEPARATOR}{file_size}".encode())

with open(file_name, "rb") as file:
    c = 0
    start_time = time.time()
    while c <= file_size:
        data = file.read(BUFFER_SIZE)
        if not (data):
            break
        sock.sendall(data)
        c += len(data)
    end_time = time.time()

print("File Transfer Complete. Total time: ", end_time - start_time)

sock.close()
```

Comment: According to your code. How should I run it. I tried and I entered my file name but the "./rec/" is what I don't understand. What does it do? Getting an error that "./rec/" directory is not found. Repeating that I have no knowledge of python what so ever. Thanks.

Comment: "./rec/" would be a directory named "rec" in the location where the server file is located. I took that directly from the code you provided in the question.